# Is there a D3 Gauge allowing multiple series/columns?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, gauge, c3

I'm looking for something like this in D3 or C3js:

[image: Multi Gauge]

The default Gauge Chart in C3 takes in multiple columns as data, but then displays them on the same line, so they are overriding eachother.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Angular 4 you can use `ngx-charts`, which provides an easily configurable multi-series gauge.  This is their [demo page](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/bar-vertical) or just checkout their [github repo](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts).  The package is written using D3 so you can likely customize it more if needed by forking the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make more then one gauge's ?
If you choice the inner and outer radious ok, you can make 4 gauge's with only 2 values, so you have only 2 sections per donut pie / gauge.
Not the easiest option but a nice workaround.

Comment: I've just constructed 3 gauges and resized them so the result looks like the one in the picture above, however that way the mouse-over is lost for all but the gauge on top...